# How to make gcc warn undefined struct?

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, sizeof, gcc-warning

I have a struct defined in .h

```
struct buf_stats {
   // ***
};
```

then in .c file

```
struct buf_stats *bs = malloc(sizeof(struct buf_states*)) ;
```

where `buf_states` is a typo.

but gcc does not warn me, although I used `-Wall`

and this bug/typo cost me 3 hours to find out.

How to make gcc warn undefined struct like this?

Comment: Heh? What was the error message you got?

Comment: @SouravGhosh I think there was NO error message and that is what OP is asking about.

Comment: Dou want to malloc enough space for a pointer? Compiler does not really need the size of what it is pointing to for that. Or do you want to malloc for a struct? In that case, there is another typo, the second `* `.

Comment: You may even write `struct XXX *bs = malloc(sizeof(struct YYY*));` and you still don't get any error. Only when you write `bs->something` you'll get a compilation error.

Comment: It would still be wrong even if you didn't make the typo

Comment: As others explained there are legitimate reasons to use pointers to opaque `struct`-s. If you want to be warned, you could spend weeks to write your GCC plugin (or your [GCC MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) extension) to check that. Are you sure it is worth spending that much efforts?  3 hours wasted is not that much (and with a code review could be less).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In your code

```
  struct buf_stats *bs = malloc(sizeof(struct buf_states*)) ;
```

is wrong for many reasons, like

- You are using an undefined type (as you mentioned)
- You are allocating way less memory (allocating for a *pointer-to-type* instead of the *type*)

But you compiler can't help much in _this_case for this particular type of error, as

- a pointer to (*any*) type in a platform has a defined size, for that the structure (i.e. the type of the variable to which it points to) need not be complete (*defined*). This is the reason we can have self-referencing structures, right?
- `malloc()` has no idea about the target variable type. It just reads the argument for the needed size, return a pointer (which is of type `void *`) to the allocated memory and upon assignment, that gets changed to the target type. It cannot possibly calculate the *mismatch* in the target size (type) with the allocated memory size.

Most convenient and simplest way to *avoid* these type of mistakes is, not to use the hard-coded type directly as the operand of `sizeof`, rather, use the variable reference.

Something like

```
 struct buf_stats *bs = malloc(sizeof *bs) ; // you can write that as (sizeof (*bs)) also
                                             // sizeof *bs === sizeof (struct buf_stats)
```

which is equivalent to

```
 struct buf_stats *bs = malloc(sizeof(struct buf_stats)) ;
```

but is more robust and less error prone.

Notes:

1. You don't need the parenthesis if the operand is not a *type name*.
2. This statement does not need any modification upon changing the type of target variable `bs`.

Comment: It is probably worth mentioning that the `*` in `sizeof *bs` does *not* indicate a pointer, but a dereference. `bs` is a pointer, so `*bs` is the struct value itself, on which sizeof is called here.

Comment: In addition, note 1 is good because it actually will produce an error similar to what @Sato is asking for, in the event that either `struct but_stats` is not complete, or `bs` is a type name instead of a variable name.

Comment: I've seen platforms for which pointers to different-sized things were different sizes. (void * was the largest pointer to any data type to make this work.)

Comment: @Joshua: in general pointers to different types can have different representations (including sizes), but there are exceptions: types that are compatible except for qualifiers must be the same, `void*` and all `char*` ditto, all `struct*`, and all `union*`. See 6.2.5p28 in C11 (n1570) or p26 in C99.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085: I used one where sizeof(char *) == 2 while sizeof(const char *) == 3! Amusingly; (char *)(const char *)char_pointer worked anyway even when the cast couldn't be optimized out.

Answer (score 17):

You can't. Using an expression like `struct foo *` (a pointer to some struct type) *declares* that struct as an *incomplete type*. A size isn't known, but it's not necessary for the size of the *pointer*.

That said, the code looks wrong, as you need the **size of the struct** (**not** the size of the pointer), so with the following code:

```
struct buf_stats *bs = malloc(sizeof(struct buf_states));
```

you would get an **error**.

There's a better way to write such code:

```
struct buf_stats *bs = malloc(sizeof *bs);
```

The expression `*bs` has the correct type for `sizeof`, even when you later change the type.